# Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal arquivo.java

Tags: java

Oi,

Estive tentando fazer um código executar em um ambiente novo, mas não estou tendo sucesso.

Sempre que abro o cmd e executo o `java arquivo.java` eu tenho como retorno o erro `Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal arquivo.java`.

A classe já foi compilada sem nenhum problema e, teoricamente, está tudo certo.

Minhas variáveis de ambiente:

`JAVA_HOME`:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

`CLASSPATH`:

> .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\htmlconverter.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar;

`PATH`:

> *variaveis irrelevantes *;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Alguma ideia do que eu posso estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Verifique se no seu código tem o método Main

Comment: Oi. O código tem o método main. Parece algo mais geral, visto que eu não estou conseguindo executar nem mesmo classes extremamente simples que criei só pra testar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário compilar a classe antes de rodar.

E para rodar, na classe é preciso conter o método main.

Ex:

```
public class Arquivo {
  public static void main(String args[]) { 

  }
}
```

Comando para compilar

```
javac Arquivo.java
```

Comando para rodar, mas não pode e não precisa usar a extensão.

```
java Arquivo
```

Comment: Parece que o erro foi eu ter executado com a extensão .java e dentro da pasta do pacote.

Rodando fora da pasta do pacote com `java pacote/classe` ele funciona.

Valeu :)

Comment: E @Lucas, vc consegue mesmo dentro da pasta (`java classe`). O erro foi colocar .java.