# Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

Tags: java, classes, cmd

já tentei: [Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal arquivo.java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104099/n%c3%a3o-foi-poss%c3%advel-localizar-nem-carregar-a-classe-principal-arquivo-java/242132#242132)

já mexi no sistema e ainda n funciona tipo quando uso `javac arquivo` `javac -version` `java -version` tudo funciona mais quando uso `java arquivo` n funciona n sei oque esta acontecendo e tudo pelo cmd.

Estou começando a aprender a usar java.

Código:

```
class main {
public static void main (String[]args){

    System.out.println("Ola mundo");




}
```

}

Comment: Onde está o código que está tentando rodar? Adiciona na pergunta.

Comment: o código e simples class main {
 public static void main (String[]args){
 
  System.out.println("Ola mundo");
 
 
 
 
 }
}

Comment: Por favor, clique em EDITAR e adicione a classe completa que está tentando compilar e gera este erro.

Comment: Exceto pelo nome minusculo de classe, creio que o problema seja o mesmo das duas perguntas que linkei. Tente novamente seguindo a recomendação das respostas das duas, ou edite este pergunta detalhando melhor seu problema, se possivel com prints.

Comment: já tentei esse que vc mandou mais ainda n vai já tentei varias das que tem aqui e em outros foruns

Comment: Tem duas perguntas, veja ambas. Se não funcionar, siga minha recomendação do ultimo comentario editando a pergunta.

Comment: O nome da sua clase é `main` com letra minúscula mesmo? Não é um bom nome, mas se for isso mesmo, certifique-se que ela está dentro de um arquivo chamado `main.java` (com letra minúscula). Em seguida, tente rodar `javac main.java` e por último `java main`. Se não funcionar, diga qual foi o erro que deu.

Comment: fiz tudo que vc falou e deu isso Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal main
Causada por: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main vo tentar mudar o nome da classe

Comment: funcionou usei 'java ola'