# Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal OlaMundo.java

Tags: java, compilação

Estou tentando compilar e rodar um "hello world" em Java pela linha de comando.

O meu código é:

```
public class OlaMundo{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Oi , funcionou");
  }
}
```

Estou tentando rodar pela linha de comando, assim

```
$> java OlaMundo.java
```

Este erro está sendo mostrado

> Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal OlaMundo.java

Comment: Embora dê pra entender a pergunta, tenta sempre escrever sobre o problema para a pergunta ser bem avaliada. Algo como: "Quando eu tento executar o programa OlaMundo com o comando abaixo, ocorre o seguinte erro:".

Comment: Duplicata de [Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal arquivo.java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104099/18246)

Answer (score 0):

Você deve primeiro compilar com o comando `javac`:

`javac OlaMundo.java`

E depois rodar com o comando `java`:

`java OlaMundo`

Comment: Bom dia ,eu fiz isso e não deu certo

Comment: @FutebolArtsVariados aparece algum erro?